# When not to use です

Tags: hiragana

さくらは青い = Sakura is blue

さくらは青いです also = Sakura is blue

Google use the first one as default. How do we know when it's ok not to use desu?

Comment: Firstly never trust Google for Japanese translations. Both sentences are correct, though if Sakura is blue she may need to go to hospital. See this link for an explanation: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33986/7944

Comment: You should read up on "Teineigo" or the "Polite form" of Japanese speech. Both sentences are correct and mean the same, the first one is more casual though, and the latter is more polite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this sentence structured correctly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33655/is-this-sentence-structured-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

If you're a beginner, this is the general rule: add です after any adjective or noun in formal sentences if the verb is "to be". In informal sentences, the verb "to be" is not です, but だ, and you can choose to say it or omit it in both nouns and な-adjectives. With い-adjectives (like this case), you can't say だ, so you always omit it.