# What's the most common way to say you are bad at something?

Tags: usage, word-usage

Would I just use わるい？　Or is there a more specific word for being unskilled at something?

私の日本語は悪いです。< Would something like this suffice?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32370/9831　・ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33655/9831

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several ways to say "I'm bad at Japanese". The most common (and direct) ways to say it would be:

> - 私は日本語が[下手]{へた}です。(*lit.* As for me, Japanese is poor.)
> - 私の日本語は下手です。(*lit.* My Japanese is poor.)

悪い is a literal translation of the English "bad". In Japanese, you don't use 悪い to say you're bad/unskillful at something.

You could also express it as "I'm not good at Japanese":

> - 私は日本語が[上手]{じょうず}ではありません。(*lit.* As for me, Japanese is not good/skillful.)
> - 私は日本語が[上手]{うま}くありません。(*lit*. As for me, Japanese is not good.)

Depending on what you're bad at, you could also use [苦手]{にがて}, which is closer to "weak":

> - 私は[料理]{りょうり}が苦手です。(≂ 私は料理が下手です。)
>     I'm bad at cooking.
> - 私は[泳]{およ}ぎが(or[水泳]{すいえい}が)苦手です。(≂ 私は泳ぎが/水泳が下手です。)
>     I'm bad at swimming.
> - 私は数学が苦手です。(but not 私は数学が下手です。)
>     I'm weak at maths.
> - 私は英語が苦手です。(When talking about English as a school subject, use 苦手. You don't use 下手 for school subjects.)
>     I'm weak at English.

This time you can rephrase them as "not good/strong at~~" using [得意]{とくい}:

> - 私は料理が得意ではありません。
>     I'm not good at cooking.
> - 私は数学が得意ではありません。(but not 私は数学が上手ではありません。)
>     I'm not strong at maths.

Comment: What makes 私は数学が下手です less natural sounding?

Comment: @A.Ellett そうなんですよね・・・　I don't know why but we don't use [下手]{へた}, [上手]{じょうず} for school subjects.. You'd use 得意, 苦手  instead.

Comment: Actually, that's as much as an explanation as I need.  I would imagine then it's the difference between a skill (an ability to speak) as opposed to persevering through the tedium of a class or lecture.

Comment: One "gotcha" to remember is that 苦手 can be used to express dislike, especially for food. 私は肉が苦手です　is a valid way to say beef doesn't agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could just use 下手｛へた｝ that is basically the opposite of 上手.

So basically you could say　私は日本語が下手です。

To add one more you could probably use 苦手{にがて} as well， which means 
"poor (at something), weak, unskilled" etc. So you would say 私は日本語が苦手です。

Comment: What about まずい？

Comment: Never heard it in that context, but a native speaker would know better. Maybe I could add 苦手 to say that you are not good at it.

Comment: OOh, I like that.  I hadn't thought of that one.  Add it for sure.  :-)

Comment: About mazui, I have a feeling it wouldn't sound so natural although the meaning would be probably clear. Maybe a native speaker could comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most natural would be

私は日本語があまり上手じゃありません。

lit. My japanese is really not very good.

Comment: How about reviewing words like 下手{へた} and まずい for a more complete answer?

Answer (score 1):

Actually 下手 (the kanji opposite of 上手) is a common way of saying you are not very good at something.

私の日本語は下手です。

Alc reference here:

[http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e4%b8%8b%e6%89%8b](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%B8%8B%E6%89%8B)

Answer (score 0):

My teacher told me using 上手 with yourself sounds pretty bad. There was another expression but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I would guess you're thinking of 得意.  Have you looked at the other answers?